# On ACF field update push field value to WooCommerce meta value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin fields on a woocommerce (accommodation bookings) product, and when an ACF field is updated I want to push those values to a specific woocommerce field.

The booking plugins used are the 
Woocommerce Booking - Booking and Reservation and
Woocommerce Accommodation Bookings (An accommodations bookings extension to the main woocommerce bookings plugin)

(1. Can anyone show me the code to do something like this? I did tons of Google searches but could not find any helpful solutions.

2. Once I have the code to update the fields, how do I find the specific woocommerce hook for each specific wc field?
3. Also, how do I tell wc product be a accommodation bookings type?)

Edit:
ACF has a code to update a field based on another field
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/
So, My question here is how to tweak the code so that when an ACF field, which is attached to the product post type, is updated, can automatically use that fields' value for a woocommerce product data value.

An example would be I have an ACF field  'Price per night', and I put a number to that field. When I click to update that product, I want that number to automatically go in the woocommerce product data of Standard Price.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OverFlow… Please, the rule is one question at the time… see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it's all one question. I just wrote it out like this to make sure my question is understood by all.

Comment: The step 3 is another different question…

Answer (score 2):

You didn't search very well see [this simple search with "ACF action hook when update a field"](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ACF%20action%20hook%20when%20update%20a%20field).

The first link is the good one and the hook to be used is something like:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 1);
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // bail early if no ACF data
    if( empty($_POST['acf']) ) {
        return;
    }

    // An array of fields values
    $fields = $_POST['acf'];

    // Get a specific field value and push to a specific Woocommerce meta data
    if ( isset($fields['field_abc123']) ) {
        $field_abc123 =  $fields['field_abc123'];

        // Push to a specific woocommerce meta data:
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'targeted_meta_key', sanitize_text_field( $field_abc123 ) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: I saw that but it does not explain how to put the acf value in to the woocommerce product data

Comment: @Gary65 That is another question… You are asking multiple questions at once… you should start asking with step 3… Nobody can guess what are your ACF settings and what booking plugin you are using… So your comment question is not answerable. This answer  answers point 1 and 2.